# ORDER BY a result column AFTER a native JPA/Hibernate query has executed

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Say I have the following native SQL:

```
SELECT a, b, c + d AS cd
FROM stuff
```

I know it's easy to just sort it using `order by`.

I was just wondering if JPA/Hibernate has a way to specify ordering AFTER the query executes and the results have returned, e.g. for sorting by the `cd` column. Basically something like a Comparator (except it's built into the ORM).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not that i know of.  but i would say that your db is usually much more efficient at sorting the data than any code you would write.  i would stuck with letting the db do i.

Answer (score 0):

JPA offers "ORDER BY" support, I'm using it. You can use following syntax.

> **SELECT a, b, c + d AS cd FROM stuff ORDER BY cd [DESC/ASC];**